# How to resolve GNU make producing a "circular main.c" error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

//makefile.conf

```
.SUFFIXES : .c .o

cc = gcc
CFLAG = -c
OFLAG = -o
O2FLAG = -O2
WPIFLAG = -lwringPi
RM = rm -rf

TARGET_SRCS = main.c
TARGET_OBJS = $(TARGET_SRCS:$.c=$.o)
TARGET_NAMES = $(TARGET_SRCS:$.c=$)
BINARY_NAME = LED_TEST
```

// makefile

```
include makefile.conf

$(TARGET_OBJS) : $(TARGET_SRCS)
        $(CC) $(O2FLAG) $(CFLAG) $(OFLAG) $^
```

I'm trying to figure out how gnu make works and how to use it. Yet, I'm a beginner.

I'm trying to use make on my assignment (not mandatory, just my passion) for running simple code which lights up LED by using wiringpi.

Actually there's only one main.c and what I want to make is the makefile that runs

```
gcc -O2 -c -o main.o main.c

gcc -o main main.o -lwiringPi
```

Since my last code didn't worked, (constantly getting circular main.c <- main.c dependency dropped error)

I tried to make a code that only runs

```
gcc -O2 -c -o main.o main.c
```

but I still get circular main.c error and I don't know what that means.

I tried to look up gnu make manuals but I thought through that, it will take my life to understand.

So I'm trying to see  the codes and make one with what I saw.

I think I understand the concept of makefile.conf but **still don't understand the function of .SUFFIXES.**

I understood it as noticing make that I'll make a rule with .c and .o, codes after that in makefile.conf defines the variables those will be used in makefile.

**How can I correct the code?** When actual 'assignment' took only five minute including adding comments.

Comment: Just to mention, the reason for your original messages about circular dependencies is because you are using the wrong syntax for your functions: both of these: `$(TARGET_SRCS:$.c=$.o)` and `$(TARGET_SRCS:$.c=$)` are wrong because the pattern character is `%` not `$`.  These should be: `$(TARGET_SRCS:%.c=%.o)` and `$(TARGET_SRCS:%.c=%)`.  However the first one would have worked anyway by accident, so I don't think you've accurately pasted the makefile you were actually using here.

Answer (score 2):

**First makefile:**

```
main:
    gcc -O2 -c -o main.o main.c
    gcc -o main main.o -lwiringPi
```

When that works perfectly, **second makefile:**

```
main: main.o
    gcc -o main main.o -lwiringPi

main.o: main.c
    gcc -O2 -c -o main.o main.c
```

When that works perfectly, **third makefile:**

```
main: main.o
    gcc -o $@ $^ -lwiringPi

main.o: main.c
    gcc -O2 -c -o $@ $<
```

When that works perfectly, you will be ready for more advanced techniques.

Comment: Thanks. From all these comments, now I realized that I've been in hurry. Like always, I should start from basic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really new, it's often helpful to start off with simple makefiles till you need the extra features.

```
main: main.c
        gcc -O2 -o main -lwiringPi main.c
```

Note the white space before the `gcc` is a single tab character.

Once you get the hang of that, you can then substitute various items to make your "make rules" easier to duplicate and maintain.  For example, `%^` means "every dependent source, so a rewrite of the rule would be

```
main: main.c
        gcc -O2 -o main -lwiringPi $^
```

Occasionally, you might want to offer easy reconfiguration of the compiler, so if you had a dozen rules, and wanted to configure the compiler all in one place

```
CC=gcc

main: main.c
        $(CC) -O2 -o main -lwiringPi $^
```

would expand the `CC` variable to the value `gcc` at make time.  There's an upper limit to the utility of this expansion, for example, if something is "one of many of the same thing"  You might not want to declare a variable for that individual item.  For example, your `WPIFLAG` is likely always required, and probably not very successfully reconfigurable.  Mabye a loader flags variable makes more sense.

```
LDFLAGS=-lwiringPi -lm -lwhatever
```

and a compiler flags variable

```
CFLAGS=-O2 -Werror -Wfatal-errors
```

Which would lead to the more sensible

```
main: main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o main $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

Finally, you can replace the target `main` in this case, with another special variable. `$@` which means "the target being built"

```
main: main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

Note that for object files, you are listing all your objects as being dependent on all of your sources.  If you want to support independent rules for object building, you need to do something different

```
main: main.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

And you'll need rules for each object.

```
main.o: main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

but it will become a labor typing this rule for each object.  To automate this rule, you will use a pattern based on the file suffixes, and a suffix rule.

```
.SUFFIXES : .o .c

.c.o :
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Note the rule above relies on the default behavior of $(CC) which is to generate a `something.o` when `something.c` is compiled with the `-c` flag.  If you wanted to make the output file explicit

```
.SUFFIXES : .o .c

.c.o :
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

This Suffix Rule acts as a macro.  When someone needs `thing.o`, it will build it from `thing.c` if `thing.c` exists, even if there isn't an explicit rule for `thing.c`

With this, you can then collect all your object on the original `main` target.  (We will remove CFLAGS, as no compiling will be happening, only linking)

```
main: main.o other.o first.o list.o end.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

But some find listing the object to be a pain, and like to put them in a variable

```
main: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

which means you will need to declare and set `OBJS`

```
OBJS = main.o other.o first.o list.o end.o
```

But it's sort of weird to track intermediate files, so why not track the actual sources

```
SOURCES = main.c other.c first.c list.c end.c
```

Ok, but how will we get the required `OBJS` from `SOURCES`?  We will derefence `SOURCES`, modifying the suffixes to `.o`

```
OBJS = ${SOURCES:.c=.o}
```

The end result

```
SOURCES = main.c other.c first.c list.c end.c
OBJS = ${SOURCES:.c=.o}

CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-O2 -Werror -Wfatal-errors
LDFLAGS=-lwiringPi -lm -lwhatever


.SUFFIXES : .o .c

.c.o :
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

main: ${OBJS}
        $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

Comment: Part of the reason your original won't work is because in all of your variable choices, you removed the expanded text of `-o main` replacing it with `-o` which is picking the first object file, which is probably `-o main.o` which doesn't make sense as it's a source too.  Hence the error.

Comment: I also recommend O'Reilly publisher's Manage projects with Make, by Andrew Oram and Steve Talbott.  It is relatively thin, easy to read, and used copies are plentiful if you look hard enough.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I realized I've been too impatient to actually understand what's what. Thank you so much. Fully understanding your answers would take some times and I'n quiet sure that it'll help me a lot.

Comment: By the way, I still can't find about -O2 option on internet. Can you tell me what that is??

Comment: the `-O2` option is an option to the `gcc` complier. With luck, `man gcc` or `info gcc` will help you find out what that means (I don't know ;-)). Glad you got your problem sorted. It is considered good form to upvote answers that help you and "accept" the answer that explicitly solves your problem. Doing so gives the writers reputation points which they have clearly earned here. Good luck.

Comment: @VunterSlaush `-O2` is an optimization flag.  It basically means "apply lightweight optimizations, or level 2 optimizations.  So what is written will work the same as the text of the code, and comparisons will mostly be reasonable; but, sometimes it might drop a unused variable, or rewrite something for speed.  With `-03` and higher the output executable should have less of the structure of the input text, but should produce the runtime output; possibly even faster.  Lower `-O` settings are easier to debug.  Higher ones might not always work, and produce faster executable times.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Jesus, thank you for the comment. I actually wandered around on Google for 3 freaking hours to find that out!

Comment: @VunterSlaush Yeah, these small 2 or 3 character things are a pain to google.  Especially when they contain non-alphabet characters.  If you knew it was an optimization, "gcc optimization" would have landed you there faster; but, how would one know?  Next time look into GCC compiler flags.  There are a ton of them and you'll probably only use about 10%.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Thanks for tip. I really need to make it instinct to check what am I missing and look them on the manuals when I'm stuck.